# jQuery: is it possible to make ID/class-less elements change on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example css:

```
div {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Example html:

```
<div>apple 1</div>
<div>apple 2</div>
<div>apple 3</div>
```

Is it possible to bind jquery clicks to these, so that the clicked div will change background color to blue, and the others will revert back to the default color?

I'm thinking something like:

```
$("div").click(function() {
   // first change all to default color
   $("div").each( background-color: green; }
   // then change the clicked div to blue
   how to get the clicked element in here I dont know.
});
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/

Comment: You should make a div with a class around your apples! With ``$('div').click`` you get **every** div on the whole page. If you want that, just ignore my note. :)

Comment: @dervampyr yes, i have that on the actual page :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to refer to the clicked element:

```js
    $("div").click(function() {
       // first change all to default color
       $("div").css('background-color', 'green')
       // then change the clicked div to blue
       $(this).css('background-color','blue');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Apple 1</div>
<div>Apple 2</div>
<div>Apple 2</div>
```

Further reading:

> [JQuery's this: demystified - by Remy Sharp](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified)

Comment: what will `$("div").each( background-color: green; }` do?

Comment: Yeah left that in by mistake

Comment: As we don't know what JQuery version OP is using, best to stick with the method they are using.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$("div").click(function() {
   // first change all to default color
   $('div').css( 'background-color', 'green');
$(this).css( 'background-color', 'blue');
alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The clicked element will be `$(this)`, so `$(this).css("background-color", "green");` will color your clicked element, `$("div").removeAttr("style")` will remove all defined colors from the rest.

So:

```
$("div").click(function() {
    // remove the style attribute from every 'div' element to reset it to the value defined in CSS
    $("div").removeAttribute("style");
    // use $(this) to apply the color the clicked element itself
    $(this).css({"background-color": "green"});
});
```